# How to verify the rank-nullity theorem for the linear application $\frac{d}{dx}\in \operatorname{End}(\mathbb{K}[x]_2)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I know that the rank-nullity theorem states that let $T: V\rightarrow W$ be a linear transformation, then:

$$ \operatorname{Rank}(T)+ \operatorname{Nullity}(T)=\dim(V)$$

But since $\frac{d}{dx}\in  \operatorname{End}(\mathbb{K}[x]_2)$ is also a linear transformation, I want to verify the rank-nullity theorem with this particular situation.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by $\Bbb K[x]_2$?

Comment: Clarification question, is $\mathbb{K}[x]_2$ the ring of polynomials of $\mathbb{K}$ localized at the ideal $2$ or is $\mathbb{K}$ the field with 2 elements?

Comment: $\mathbb{K}[x]_2$ is _the ring of polynomials of  localized at the ideal 2_ $(ax^2+bx+c)$

Comment: You can just take a proof of the abstract theorem and then substitute everything there with your example.